# How to convert calendar year to water year in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

This question has been solved with R, but I haven't seen useful examples with Python. I would like to learn how to convert calendar year (1/1/1990 to 12/31/2010) discharge data to water year data (i.e. 10/01/1990 to 9/31/2010). Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: `df['date'] =  df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=9)`

Answer (score 2):

- Using data from [USGS 03335500 WABASH RIVER AT LAFAYETTE, IN](https://waterdata.usgs.gov/in/nwis/uv?site_no=03335500)

  - Dates: 2001-10-01 - 2017-09-31
- The `'datetime'` column must be set to a `datetime` `dtype` by importing the data with `parse_dates`, or using `pd.to_datetime()` after importing the data.
- Use [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to determine the water year.

  - Use the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) to extract `month` and `year` numbers.
  - If the month number is less than 10, the water year is the `.dt.year`, otherwise, the water year is the `.dt.year + 1`
  - 13 times faster than the `.apply` function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615358/7758804), for the `282757` rows in this DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('WabashRiver_Flow.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])

# drop na values
df = df.dropna()

# determine the water year
df['water_year'] = df.datetime.dt.year.where(df.datetime.dt.month < 10, df.datetime.dt.year + 1)

# display(df.head())
  agency_cd  site_no            datetime tz_cd  discharge_cfps  water_year
0      USGS  3335500 2001-10-01 00:00:00   EST            2610        2002
1      USGS  3335500 2001-10-01 01:00:00   EST            2610        2002
2      USGS  3335500 2001-10-01 02:00:00   EST            2610        2002
3      USGS  3335500 2001-10-01 03:00:00   EST            2630        2002
4      USGS  3335500 2001-10-01 04:00:00   EST            2630        2002
```

#### Calculate the mean discharge rate by water year

```py
annual_mean_discharge_rate = df.groupby('water_year')[['discharge_cfps']].mean()

# display(annual_mean_discharge_rate)
            discharge_cfps
water_year                
2002           9379.829589
2003           8678.468324
2004           8562.505005
2005           8928.776256
2006           6710.805312
2007          10331.564789
2008          10626.336623
2009           8972.046607
2010           5298.569557
2011          10519.540869
2012           9013.624424
2013           9007.924205
2014           9079.561658
2015          12267.393776
2016           6445.875810
2017          10240.721464

annual_mean_discharge_rate.plot.bar(figsize=(8, 6), xlabel='Water Year', ylabel='Discharge (cubic feet / sec)', legend=False)
```

[image]

---

### `%%timeit` comparison

- [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) compared to [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), and the function from the other answer.

  - `.Series.where` is vectorized, while `.apply` is not.

```py
import numpy as np

# function from other answer; updated because pd.datetime is deprecated
def assign_wy(row):
    if row.month>=10:
        return(row.year + 1)
    else:
        return(row.year)


%%timeit
df.datetime.dt.year.where(df.datetime.dt.month < 10, df.datetime.dt.year + 1)
[out]:
66.9 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
df.datetime.apply(lambda v: np.where(v.month >= 10, v.year + 1, v.year))
[out]:
1.38 s ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df.datetime.apply(lambda x: assign_wy(x))
[out]:
861 ms ± 9.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and write your own function to create a new column `WY`:

IF you have have `df`:

```
                 Date  Discharge
0 2011-10-01 00:00:00  0.0
1 2011-10-01 01:00:00  0.0
2 2011-10-01 02:00:00  0.0
3 2011-10-01 03:00:00  0.0
4 2011-10-01 04:00:00  0.0
```

Then:

```
import pandas as pd

def assign_wy(row):
    if row.Date.month>=10:
        return(pd.datetime(row.Date.year+1,1,1).year)
    else:
        return(pd.datetime(row.Date.year,1,1).year)

df['WY'] = df.apply(lambda x: assign_wy(x), axis=1)
```