# Iterating a custom date range over multiple years in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The short of it: How do I parse through yearly data in non-standard year. In my case Sept to Sept.

I've got a script to parse through years' worth of hourly temperature data and calculate the accumulated growing degree days (GDD) per year. Some demo data and the script are on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/plytheman/9156cc88d05ba0af2a1b0d395839c479) if you're curious where I'm at. The meat and potatoes though is getting the yearly cumulative sum with this:

```
df[col_name] = df.resample('Y')['dGDD'].cumsum()
```

and all works well. Each day will show the accumulated GDD in the proper column until Dec 31 when it starts from zero again.

My next goal is to calculate Chilling Degree Days which works similarly as GDD but it runs from Sept to Sept each year and I have no idea how to work that in (or what to properly google for help). I know I can set a date range to run it over, ie `df['2012-9-1':'2013-9-1']` but I'm not sure how to automate it for the entirety of my data (2007-2018).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out the period of time I'm looking for is known as a 'Water Year'. Learning that lead me to another [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105804/reorder-data-frame-from-calendar-year-to-water-year-using-python). That, combined with a closer look at the `.resample()` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) where I learned you can direct the resample to something other than index, got me this:

```
df['WaterYear'] = df.index + pd.DateOffset(months=-8)
df[col_name] = df.resample('Y', on='WaterYear')['dCDD'].cumsum()
```

And everything seems to be working swimmingly now.